# Avoid similar controller actions

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I am building a bundle for private messages between my users.

Here is my inbox action from my controller. What it does is fetches the current user's messages, it passes the query to KNPpaginator to display a part of them. I also save how many results to be displayed on the page in the database. One form is a dropdown that sends how many results to display per page. The other form is made of checkboxes and a dropdown with actions. Based on which action was selected, I pass the id's of the messages(selected checkboxes id's) to another function called markAction(which is also a page that can mark one single message by going to the specific url)

```
 public function inboxAction(Request $request)
    {

        $messages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PrivateMessageBundle:Message');
        $mymsg = $messages->findMyMessages($this->getUser());

        $message_settings = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PrivateMessageBundle:MessageSettings');

        $perpage = $message_settings->findOneBy(array('user' => $this->getUser()));
        $pagerform = $this->createForm(new MessageSettingsType(), $perpage);


        $pagerform->handleRequest($request);
        if ($pagerform->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($perpage);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $mymsg,
            $request->query->get('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            $perpage ? $perpage->getResPerPage() : 10/*limit per page*/,
            array('defaultSortFieldName' => 'a.sentAt', 'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc')
        );

        $form = $this
            ->createForm(
                new ActionsType(),
                $mymsg->execute()
            );


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $ids = array();

            foreach ($data['checkboxes'] as $checkbox) {
                $ids[] = $checkbox->getId();
            }

            $action = $data['inboxactions'];


            $this->markAction($action, $ids);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('private_message_inbox');

        }

        return $this->render(
            '@PrivateMessage/inbox.html.twig',
            array(
                'messageList' => $pagination,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'pagerform' => $pagerform->createView(),
            )
        );
    }
```

And the mark action user in my inbox controller. Based on one parameter, I apply the respective action to the second parameter, which is one message if the page was called through routing, and can be an array of messages if called through my inboxAction. I do a few consistency checks, and then mark my message.

```
public function markAction($action, $msgs)
    {


        if (!$msgs) {
            $this->addFlash(
                'error',
                'Select at least one message!'
            );

            return;
        } else {
            if (!$action) {
                $this->addFlash(
                    'error',
                    'Select one action to apply to your items!'
                );

                return;
            } else {

                $messages = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PrivateMessageBundle:Message');
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $msg = $messages->findBy(array('receiver' => $this->getUser(), 'id' => $msgs));

                $good = 0;


                foreach ($msg as $isforme) {

                    $good++;
                    switch ($action) {
                        case 'spam': {
                            if ($isforme->getIsSpam() == false) {
                                $isforme->setIsSpam(true);
                                if (!$isforme->getSeenAt()) {
                                    $isforme->setSeenAt(new \DateTime('now'));
                                }
                                $em->persist($isforme);

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'unspam': {
                            if ($isforme->getIsSpam() == true) {
                                $isforme->setIsSpam(false);
                                $em->persist($isforme);

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'viewed': {
                            if ($isforme->getSeenAt() == false) {
                                $isforme->setSeenAt(new \DateTime('now'));
                                $em->persist($isforme);

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'unviewed': {
                            if ($isforme->getSeenAt() != false) {
                                $isforme->setSeenAt(null);
                                $em->persist($isforme);

                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        default: {
                            $this->addFlash(
                                'error',
                                'There was an error!'
                            );

                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    $em->flush();

                }
                $this->addFlash(
                    'notice',
                    $good.' message'.($good == 1 ? '' : 's').' changed!'
                );


            }
        }

        if ($action == 'unspam') {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('private_message_spam');
        } else {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('private_message_inbox');
        }

    }
```

Being kind of new to symfony, I'm not sure how good my markAction function is. I feel like it can be simplier, but I'm not sure how to make it.

Now, my actual question. How can I render other pages of my bundle, like Sent or Spam messages? The only lines from the inboxAction that I have to change are

```
 $mymsg = $messages->findMyMessages($this->getUser());
```

to have it return spam or sent messages by the user, for instance.
and

```
return $this->render(
            '@PrivateMessage/inbox.html.twig',...
```

so I actually return the respective page's view. I have already made the other pages and copied the code in the other actions, but I think I can make it so I write this code a single time, but don't know how.

Everything else is EXACTLY the same. How can I not copy and paste this code in all of the other actions and make it a bit more reusable?

Comment: Could create an abstract controller to have your main controller inherit instead of inheriting the default Symfony2 controller. Put those functions in the abstract controller and label them as protected, or at least put the common code in there...Numerous examples on the web, if you think that's the right path.

Comment: The problem is that part of the action method (the 2 lines of code I told about above) differ. So if I declare it as abstract, how can I make the controller that inherits implement 2 actions different on those two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could strart to change your routing more dynamic:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
mailclient:
    path:      /mailclient/{page}
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Mailclient:index, page: "inbox" }
```

Resulting that this routes:

```
/mailclient
/mailclient/inbox
/mailclient/sent
/mailclient/trash
```

will all call the same action.

Now your method (Action) will get an extra parameter:

```
public function indexAction($page, Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

Through this parameter you know what the user likes to see. Now you can start to write your code more dynamic. You can consider to add some private functions to your controller class that you can call from the indexAction or 
you could simply create your own classes too.

Comment: So in this indexAction all I have to do is make a switch based on the page and fill those variables based on it. I like this approach a lot, but is there no other way? I'd like to be flexible. Another thing, I applied my  markAction to 1000 messages and it game me timeout. Should it do that? Isn't it supposed to be fast? I'm thinking I do something wrong with it. That's why I was looking for alternatives, to make it work properly.

Comment: There are always other ways but i think this will help you a lot :-) . Take a look at the KNP paginatorBundle (https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) to divide the messages into multiple pages.

Comment: I already did that. My messages on all my pages are split 10 per page. I was asking how to not repeat the code for inbox, sent, spam pages.

Comment: Well sometimes it is not so easy to understand the questions. I think i should only apply actions to only one page (in your case 10 messages). Otherwise the controller should deny the action.

Comment: But what if I want to make the user mark ALL of his questions as read? That will check each message's state and mark it if it's unmarked. For 1000 messages that timed out, so I think I did something wrong, because I think it should be fast. I'm already marking the messages selected from the current page(the 10 ones), but I want to have a separate button to have them mark all the messages.

Comment: I wonder which user wants to mark 1000 messages? For performance it is important to setup your database as good as possible. And of course how fast your server will be. You can also increase your timeout in the php.ini file or via the ini_set function: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // five minutes. But this all is beyond scope of your original question ;-). Also: do not execute queries in a foreach loop but write one query who change all records in once

Comment: I think that's where I went wrong with it. Thanks, will do.